# Preventing other Editors from Pasting the Conditional Format of a Cell when they use CTRL+V

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

[image](EXAMPLE On The TOP IMAGE) On the LEFT Side, people will need to compile tickets, such tickets require Serial Numbers that are found on the RIGHT Side, so when people compile a ticket they will copy a Serial Number from the RIGHT into the LEFT. After that they would need to Cancel the Serial Numbers copied to prevent them from using the same Serial Number later on.

So because I wanted to make this more automatic, instead of making them cancelling the Serial Numbers, I made a Conditional Format that would highlight the Serial Numbers that have been used, so that people will instantly know which one got used. (EXAMPLE On The BOTTOM IMAGE)

Tho, because of the Highlight, when they copy a Serial Number they would copy also the highlight since they copy the Conditional Format.

I know the easy way to fix this is telling them to Paste with CTRL+SHIFT+V but some of them would forget to do it.

I'm looking for a workaround to prevent this. I'd be satisfied either with a script that automatically delete the conditional format when the Serial Number gets pasted, or maybe something that turns CTRL+C into Copying Values only, or any workaround you have in mind, I'm open to suggestions.

I tried to make a Script for copying only values when people use CTRL+V but it's not working.

```js
function onEdit(){
  if(e.range.columnStart === 8){
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var activeRange=spreadsheet.getActiveRange();
    activeRange.setValues(activeRange.getValues());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Try this:

```
function onEdit(){
  if(e.range.columnStart === 8){
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var activeRange=spreadsheet.getActiveRange();
    // activeRange.setValues(activeRange.getValues());
    activeRange.clearFormat();
  }
}
```

That way the conditional formatting for that cell would be removed by the trigger and keep the same values, for example:

[image: Example gif]

I would like to mention that in my example `e.range.columnStart` was equal to `7` since "Seriale" was on column `G`, in your case this would only work if you're pasting the serial numbers on column `H` which is Column `8`.

---

#### Reference:

- [Range.clearFormat()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#clearFormat())